# PhpStorm - How to force a string to be handled as such?

Tags: php, ide, phpstorm

How can I force to be handle just as a string and not be interpreted by the IDE as something that it is not?

Granted the following string is rather unusual and gets identified as SQL by the IDE.

```php
'SELECT {$selectors} FROM `{$table}`{$where}{$order}{$limit}{$offset}'
```

As you probably guessed by now, the placeholders are seen as invalid SQL code, and give me a slew of error in the IDE.

Already attempted to "fix" those issues via **@noinspection**, but there are multiple warnings and errors detected in that one line of code, that it is not feasible to suppress those "issues" one by one.

Another drawback is that some errors require me to disable some really useful inspections and I really don't want that.

**So, is there a way just force PhpStorm to treat that one string as an actual string and not, in this case, SQL?**

Comment: @GordonM I'm well aware of prepared statements. This is just a part of an abstraction layer and might not even be the final solution for what I'm going for. So please spare me your comments, w/o knowing in what context this is used.

Comment: @GordonM Never stated that i'm an expert in anything. Rude? Maybe, but it is the truth. You can't make assumptions on how something is used without knowing the actual context. Besides, this was a question about PhpStorm not if that partial code is production worthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may disable SQL Language Injection into all strings. Downside: it affects whole project (or even ALL projects, considering the fact that it's a built-in rule and therefore it's an IDE-wide setting).

This can be done at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Language Injections`.

---

An option just for that string is to forcibly inject `Plain Text` language by placing `/** @lang Text */` *just before the string*:

```
$s2 = /** @lang Text */'SELECT {$selectors} FROM `{$table}`{$where}{$order}{$limit}{$offset}';
```

See the difference:

[image]

**P.S.** Notice the difference between interpolated string (HEREDOC in this case; but the same is for sting using `""` as delimiters) vs `''` (single quotes/NOWDOC). It still sees it as SQL but shows no warnings (which means that IDE understand that `$table` is something dynamic). *But it could be just my settings -- checking it in my few-years-old Test project...*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can customize SQL parameters from the settings under Tools | Databases. Just add your placeholder pattern. Then SQL analyzer should recognize this as valid.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Nice alternative method, chosen answer is more elegant.